# Remove "minor-publishing" div from Publish admin metabox

Tags: admin, metabox, editor, publish, customization

I want to remove the `#minor-publishing` `div` from the Publish admin metabox. I came across [How to HIDE everything in PUBLISH metabox except Move to Trash & PUBLISH button](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/36118/how-to-hide-everything-in-publish-metabox-except-move-to-trash-publish-button) and http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/adminimize/ but they either remove it by css or custom-code their metabox.

Is there a way to remove the div by hooking on to some action and modifying the html that will be outputted for that metabox?

[How to Move the Author Metabox into the "Publish" metabox?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1983/how-to-move-the-author-metabox-into-the-publish-metabox) modifies the html output by *adding* code to it. What I need is to *remove* the entire `#minor-publishing` `div` from the html that will be output for the Publish admin metabox.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short- no. The html in question is hard-coded in the [`post_submit_meta_box`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-admin/includes/meta-boxes.php#L5) callback function.

You can, of course de-register the publish metabox and re-register your own which mimics `post_submit_meta_box` (but making your alterations) and being sure to keep the names of the inputs exactly the same. This method has been outlined the following posts where a core metabox is required to be edited.:

- [custom post type taxonomies UI radiobuttons not checkboxes](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/48937/9364)
- [Custom-Taxonomy as categories: Remove "most-used" tab?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/48785/9364)

It's a lengthy function though - and would break if core ever changed decided to change the names of the inputs (though very unlikely).

In this situation I would probably recommend a CSS or javascript work-around....